# Mixing Relaxed and Release-Acquire Memory Orders

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, atomic, stdatomic

Consider `std::atomic<int> x(0)`. If I understand correctly, `std::memory_order_relaxed` guarantees only that the operation happens atomically, but provides no guarantees of synchronization. So `x.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)` 1000 times from 2 threads will have an end result of 2000 always. However, the returned value of any one of those calls is not guaranteed to reflect the true current value (e.g. the 2000th increment could return 1700 as the previous value).

But - and here's my confusion - given that those increments are happening in parallel, what would `x.load(std::memory_order_acquire)` return? Or `x.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)`? Do these return the true current value or do they have the same problem of out-of-date answers that relaxed ordering has due to the relaxed increments?

As far as I can tell, the standard only guarantees that releasing to an acquire (on the same variable) synchronizes and thus gives the true current value. So how can relaxed mix in with typical acquire-release semantics?

For instance, I've heard `std::shared_ptr`'s reference count is incremented in relaxed order and decremented in acq_rel order because it needs to ensure it has the true value in order to only delete the object once. Because of this I'm tempted to think they would give the true current value, but I can't seem to find any standardese to back it up.

Comment: I'm pretty, but not totally sure (hence comment and not answer), that relaxed synchronises the variable in question so you'll always have the correct value. It just can't be used to synchronise anything _else_ from around the calls. For `shared_ptr` you can relaxed increment (as you do nothing pre or post increment) but you must decrement with acq_rel semantics as on release to non-zero you must release any writes you did to the object it points to, and if you are the final decrementer (to zero) you must also acquire so you get other threads writes before you run destructors/free the memory.

Comment: Easiest way to wrap your head around memory model is this: 1. assume that code is executed as is (i.e. ignore reordering); 2. when your code modifies memory assume that other threads will observe modifications at an upredictable time in unpredictable order -- this is `relaxed` model. Now read about other models -- they simply provide additional guarantees wrt order of observations (of your changes) by other threads.

Comment: Hmm... I might be not entirely correct here :). Check [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-discussion/OHv-oNSuJuk/NV9q92GaCgAJ) and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Relaxed_ordering)

Comment: @C.M. Right, see i get the distinction between relaxed and the others, but I can't seem to find anything in the standard that makes mixing relaxed/non-relaxed on the same variable well-defined in terms of what the non-relaxed sees as the current value. Like - does reading with acquire still see the current value if it was updated in other threads with relaxed stores?

Comment: @MikeVine I get the need for `acq_rel` decrement, I just don't see how combining it with a `relaxed` increment is safe in terms of what the decrement would see as the current value. As far as I know, relaxed is only useful if you don't really care about being able to see up-to-date values before the end of whatever you're doing. Like if you wanted a counter for how many times a function was called - you only care about the final result.

Comment: @CruzJean The way I see it: atomic `fetch_add` imposes additional implicit requirement on order of visibility -- it is guaranteed to always observe latest value and update it atomically (or, in other words, on IA-32 even relaxed fetch_add will use LOCK prefix). So, yes -- you can use it both ways (for increment and decrement), but problem with decrement is last `--ref` is immediately followed by dtor call and that call has to be properly ordered with decrement (or it may happen before) -- hence requirement to use stricter ordering on final refcount decrement

Answer (score 2):

ISO C++ guarantees that a modification order exists for every atomic object separately.

With seq_cst there's guaranteed to be a global order where all threads can agree on `a` changing before `b` or something.  But for a *single* object, a modification order is guaranteed to exist even if some operations are relaxed.

The return values you from relaxed `fetch_add` define / record what the modification order was.  **The 2000th increment returns `2000` *by definition*, that's how you know it was the 2000th.**

> As far as I can tell, the standard only guarantees that releasing to an acquire (on the same variable) synchronizes and thus gives the true current value.

Synchronizes-with is only necessary if you care about reading *other* values, e.g. one thread stores to a non-atomic array, then does a release-store like `data_ready = 1;`.  For a reader to safely read data from the array, they need to see `data_ready != 0` with an acquire load, which means they can also see the effects of all earlier assignments in the thread that did the release-store.